# Get error when using 2nd custom layout page in identity razor pages from mvc views shared folder

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to user 2 layout page in identity 1 for login, registration and as well as public user users _webLayout and another _userLayout for authentic users who have account. When I'm using _webLayout its working fine in whole identity but when change the to _userLayout getting error like below
**error**
[image]

**Layouts**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That mean you need to add a section script in your View

```
@section scripts{
    // Add something here
}
```

when you define a section  in your Layout or add the `required: false` like

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

in your Layout.